# SonarQube 7: New code not detected by sonarqube

Tags: git, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube7

I have been trying to find new code coverage in sonarqube. I am following  below steps to get the new code committed to git so I can find coverage on it.

I have two git branches x and y. I am running sonar analysis on x and can see the analysis. Branch y has new commits, on running analysis on y. I can see new code smells, issues introduced but not new code ( under "Coverage on New Code") added in this branch over x. I can see new code in the files on sonar.

Below is the example:

Suppose I have a master branch and local branch (created from master). Analysis work fine on master and local branch at this point. I added few new commits in a local branch and merged (from git plugin in IntelliJ) it with master branch. Now when I am running analysis on master branch, I don't see new code ( under "Coverage on New Code") whereas all other parameters code smells, Bugs etc gets updated with respect to new code.

I am only able to see data under "Coverage on New Code" section if I make commits on master branch instead of merge from local.

SCM: git

Sonarqube version: 7.0

Sonarscanner version: 3.0.3

[image]

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or how to solve this issue.

Comment: What languages is this project written in?

Comment: It's in java language

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details of your analysis including how you specify your coverage report and any analysis log lines that seem relevant.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Sorry for the delayed response. I have updated the question with an example. Please let me know if any further information is required.

Comment: Do you have sovle this issue? I got the same one.

Comment: Not yet. @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Please help here